# Whether using static const lambda object causes performance loss?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

Suppose I have a recursive function `void foo()` which has to be called multiple times(e.x. 1000000x):

```
void foo()
{
    ...
    static const auto lambda = 
        [](auto x,auto y){
            ...
        }; // This lambda will capture no variable.

    foo();
}
```

Should I mark the lambda as static and const to avoid extra overhead?

Comment: The only real way to know is try both and measure.  One thing you should consider is if recursions is really the solution.  Recursion takes up a lot of the systems stack space which means you are limited to how many recursive calls can be in flight at any one time.  Iteration does not have that issue.

Comment: create a lambda object like that has no overhead (except maybe space for a empty object). whether you should have only one instance depend on the use case.

Comment: @NathanOliver This function is tail recursive though. No sane compiler would grow the stack there.

Comment: Why is this a lambda *anyway*? I mean, you're giving it a name. You're not capturing any variables. There's no point in it *being a lambda*.

Comment: @NicolBolas it restricts the scope of the name to within `foo`

Comment: @Caleth: The world is not running out of names. You can use `detail` namespaces or `static` globals to hide such things if it is warranted. C++20 modules can really help here. But this obsession some people have with "no names EVER!!" leads to lots of dubious programming techniques.

Comment: @NicolBolas I got no C++20 yet, embedded toolchain, you know... Only C++17

Comment: @Phadyer: Sure, but that doesn't change anything. Even without modules, the world is still not running out of names, and you still have plenty of ways to hide them.